# The last time I saw you was ages/has been ages ago

Tags: grammar

Do I say, *The last time I saw you was ages ago,* or, *The last time I saw you has been ages ago?*

Comment: "I last saw you ages ago"?

Comment: All of these sound awkward. Personally, I'd say "I haven't seen you in ages!" DopeGhoti's suggestion in the above comment, however, works as well.

Answer (score 4):

Interestingly, of your choices, I'd have said, *The last time I saw you was ages ago.*

However, in AmE, we usually simply say, *It's been ages!* which means, *It has been ages*, or, *I haven't seen you in ages.*

But **not** *the last time I saw you has been ages* ago. *Saw* is the past tense. It was done. *Has been* is the present perfect progressive tense, and describes an action that began in the past, continues in the present, and may continue. The two don't go together in a meaningful sense without some other construction.

It *has been* ages since I *have seen* you. The tenses match here.

Comment: There is also a well-known idiom, and widely used, of 'Long-time, no-see'. It means 'it has been a long time since we saw one another'. I'm not sure of the origin but seems to be in mimicry of people who barely spoke English, possibly American Indians.

Comment: _Has been_ is **not** the present perfect progressive; it's the simple perfect construction with a present tense auxiliary. The progressive construction always involves an _-ing_ participle. The present perfect **progressive** construction is _has been being_, as in _He's been being followed for months_.